# Differences in volume of audio content

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are having a Skill built for us which plays podcasts and audio snippets of videos. We currently serve all of this content through other traditional platforms like native mobile apps and a website.

One problem we have is that the volume of all this audio content is much lower than the rest of the sounds outputted from the Alexa device. We don't notice any similar discrepancies on the other aforementioned platforms, and the developers building the Skill say that there's no API which allows you to boost or manipulate the output volume (not the system volume).

Has anyone else had experiences with this sort of issue? We are reluctant to pump up the volume of our source files as it will affect all the other places they are listened to.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes it's tricky and you're not alone.

As detailed in [this BBC report](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/whp/whp-pdf-files/VoiceApps_DesignTips.pdf)* on designing a voice application - "All of our experts have experienced problems in audio levels when mixing and mastering audio for smart speakers."

[Official guidence](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/flashbriefing/normalizing-the-loudness-of-audio-content.html#loudness-requirements) from Amazon is:

> Program loudness for Alexa should average -14 dB LUFS/LKFS
>
> The true-peak value should not exceed -2 dBFS

It then goes so far as to say that,

> Your skill may be rejected if program loudness:
>
> Is lower than -19 dB LUFS
>
> Is higher than -9dB LUFS

However, this mainly seems to apply to audio played either as part of a Flash Briefing or using the `AudioPlayer Interface`, and you may get away with deviating from this if using it as part of SSML output.

That said, in practice developers tend to bump the levels up on audio until it sounds good. Sticking strictly to the recommendations usually renders the volume way too low.

So, if you didn't want to increase the loudness of clips as it'd affect other platforms, your best options might be to create an Alexa-version of the audio - mixed slightly louder. Though, I recognize that this would be tedious.

*In the interest of transparency, I wanted to declare that I fed into this report.